# How can I remove some objects contains on a js object according to a specified property?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object js that contains other objects like this :

```js
const USER: {
        LANGUAGE: { 
            'editable': 1,
            'decimal': 0,
            'degree': 0,
            'master': 1,
            0: ['', '', 0],  
            1: ['', '', 1], 
        },
        LUM: { 
            'editable': 1,
            'decimal': 0,
            'degree': 0,
            'master': 0,
            0: ['', '', 0], 
            1: ['', '', 1], 
            2: ['', '', 2], 
        },
        SP: { 
            'editable': 1,
            'decimal': 0,
            'degree': 0,
            'master': 1,
            0: ['', '', 0], 
            1: ['', '', 1], 
            2: ['', '', 2], 
        },
    },
};
```

I want to create another object that contains only object which contains 'master': 1;

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? And what problem did you encounter with your attempt?  Please edit your question and provide these details.

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(USER).filter(([_,v]) => v.master === 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following solutions:

```
const filteredObjects = {};

for (const key in USER) {
    if (USER[key]['master'] === 1) {
        filteredObjects[key] = USER[key];
    }
}

console.log(filteredObjects);
```

or the approach using `Object.keys` and the array methods `filter` and `reduce`.

```
const filteredObjects = Object.keys(USER)
    .filter(key => USER[key]['master'] === 1)
    .reduce((result, key) => {
        result[key] = USER[key];
        return result;
    }, {});

console.log(filteredObjects);
```

Comment: using intermediate arrays is a performance hinder

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has the methods `Object.keys()` and `Array.reduce()` which you can use to filter the objects based on their properties:

```js
const filteredUser = Object.keys(USER).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (USER[key].master === 1) {
        acc[key] = USER[key];
    }
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(filteredUser);
```

Answer (score -1):

An one-liner with `Object.entries()`:

```js
console.log(Object.entries(USER).reduce((r, [key, item]) => (item.master === 1 && (r[key] = item), r), {}));
```

```html
<script>
const USER= {
        LANGUAGE: { 
            'editable': 1,
            'decimal': 0,
            'degree': 0,
            'master': 1,
            0: ['', '', 0],  
            1: ['', '', 1], 
        },
        LUM: { 
            'editable': 1,
            'decimal': 0,
            'degree': 0,
            'master': 0,
            0: ['', '', 0], 
            1: ['', '', 1], 
            2: ['', '', 2], 
        },
        SP: { 
            'editable': 1,
            'decimal': 0,
            'degree': 0,
            'master': 1,
            0: ['', '', 0], 
            1: ['', '', 1], 
            2: ['', '', 2], 
        },
    };
</script>
```

If you want more speed, remove the destructuring:

```
` Chrome/117
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Object.entries() no destructuring   1.0x  |  x10000000   357   366   372   377   394
Object.entries()                    1.1x  |  x10000000   392   392   395   398   407
Object.keys()                       1.2x  |  x10000000   442   447   449   450   464
Dimava                              3.8x  |  x10000000  1352  1361  1370  1402  1406
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```html
<script benchmark="10000000">

    const USER= {
            LANGUAGE: { 
                'editable': 1,
                'decimal': 0,
                'degree': 0,
                'master': 1,
                0: ['', '', 0],  
                1: ['', '', 1], 
            },
            LUM: { 
                'editable': 1,
                'decimal': 0,
                'degree': 0,
                'master': 0,
                0: ['', '', 0], 
                1: ['', '', 1], 
                2: ['', '', 2], 
            },
            SP: { 
                'editable': 1,
                'decimal': 0,
                'degree': 0,
                'master': 1,
                0: ['', '', 0], 
                1: ['', '', 1], 
                2: ['', '', 2], 
            },
        };

// @benchmark Object.keys()
Object.keys(USER).reduce((r, key) => (USER[key].master === 1 && (r[key] = USER[key]), r), {});

// @benchmark Object.entries()
Object.entries(USER).reduce((r, [key, item]) => (item.master === 1 && (r[key] = item), r), {});

// @benchmark Object.entries() no destructuring
Object.entries(USER).reduce((r, entry) => (entry[1].master === 1 && (r[entry[0]] = entry[1]), r), {});

// @benchmark Dimava
function objectFilter(obj, filter) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .filter(([key, value]) => filter(value, key, obj)),
  )
}

// @run
objectFilter(USER, (e) => e.master === 1)

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: OP doesn't ask for a performant solution, and has low reputation, so understandability for beginners is preferred over performance, unless performance goes O(n^2)

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Works the same as array.filter, but with an object
 * @template O
 * @param {O} obj
 * @param { (e: O[keyof O], k: keyof O, o: O) => boolean } filter
 * @returns { Partial<O> }
 */
function objectFilter(obj, filter) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .filter(([key, value]) => filter(value, key, obj)),
  )
}

console.log(objectFilter(USER, (e) => e.master === 1))
```

Comment: an intermediate array plus `Object.fromEntries()` is slower than direct object creation, check my benchmark